# Firebase Multi Location Updates - Setting Children With Empty Values

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use multi-location updates in order to change values in the `Realtime Database` and have one listener to follow all of the changes at once.

This is what I have tried to do:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map data = new HashMap();

data.put("Users/"+senderEmail+"/friends_requests_sent/"+receiverEmail,"");
data.put("Users/"+receiverEmail+"/friends_requests_received/"+senderEmail,"");

mDatabase.updateChildren(data, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

        if (databaseError!=null)
            showConnectionErrorToast();


        else{
            Context context=getContext();
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    context.getString(R.string.friend_request_was_sent), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
});
```

The children are being added just fine (receiverEmail and senderEmail), but it forces me to put values in them, although I don't want to. **I want that the email will be the key of this children, without a value.**

Is this possible in this way?
If it's not, what will be the best alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to store a key without a value in the Firebase Database. In cases where you really don't have a value to store, consider using a marker value like `true` or `"TBD"`.